# getter called on null in flutter gives error screen

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart, error-handling, null

I have a login and an update profile screen after the login. here I am setting the user profile in the `genesis` method. I am facing weired issue. most of the time I get the below screen where I do have the information for the user. the specific column is `gender` where it was called on null is the error.

[image]

```dart
//store user data
      _user = new UserModel(
        id: data['collection']['userData']['id'].toString(),
        name: data['collection']['userData']['name'],
        email: data['collection']['userData']['email'],
        phone: data['collection']['userData']['phone_number'].toString(),
        avatar: data['collection']['userData']['avatar'],
        age: data['collection']['userData']['age'].toString(),
        gender: data['collection']['userData']['gender'].toUpperCase().toString() ?? 'MALE',
        totalscore: 100,
        // totalscore: data['collection']['userData']['total_sessions_count'],
        totaldays: data['collection']['userData']['total_session_by_days_count'],
      );
```

and above is the code in `genesis` method which stores the data locally.

in user `profile update screen` code is as following:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     final userProvider =  Provider.of<Genesis>(context, listen: false);
     _user = userProvider.user;
     print('------------------------------------');
     print(_user);
     print('------------------------------------');
    if(_firsTime){
      setState(() {
        _gender = _user.gender.toUpperCase() ?? _gender;
        _nameController.text = _user.name;
        _emailController.text = _user.email;
        _ageController.text = _user.age;
        _phoneController.text = _user.phone;
        _avatar = _user.avatar ?? 'https://placehold.it/200x200';
        _firsTime = false;
      });
    }
}

what is the issue here ?
```

Comment: what does this `print(_user);` give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can try it
>
> ```
> _gender = _user?.gender?.toUpperCase() ?? _gender;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it is pretty clear that you are calling the '`gender`' on null.

check whether your `_user` is null or not before accessing it's properties.

Comment: Yes I know that and that's why I  added the `??` condition. but still why this is the issue is confusing to me. am I calling the user data via provider in wrong way ?

Comment: without seeing the complete code we can't say why that particular variable is null